JavaScript toggle method not getting called from ASP
Note these two functions are the same, just named differently:
The following snippet is in abc.js:
function displayConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal() {
    $('[id$=a]').css('display', 'block');
}

function toggleConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal() {
    $('[id$=a]').css('display', 'block'); // I realise this is not toggling functionality, but that's not in question here/yet
}

The following snippets are all in def.aspx:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>

DOESN'T WORK:
  <button 
      id="a" 
      type="button"
      onclick="toggleConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal()">Create New</button>


DOES WORK:
  <button 
      id="a" 
      type="button"
      onclick="displayConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal()">Create New</button>


Likewise, if I use asp:Button, same issue
DOESN'T WORK:
 <asp:Button 
      id="a" 
      type="button"
      text="Create New"
      runat="server"
      onclick="toggleConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal()" />


DOES WORK:
 <asp:Button 
      id="a" 
      type="button"
      text="Create New"
      runat="server"
      onclick="displayConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal()" />

The JavaScript code should run in both cases, making a modal show.
I even did a clean and rebuild before each attempt.
I added all this code, so the problem isn't to do with something else: it's all new code and only the display* method works. This behaviour is making me ask: is toggle* a special word in JavaScript or asp?
I'm pretty new to asp and wanted to understand what is going on, as this sort of bug could cause me a lot of wasted time in the future, should such errors be for a reason that I don't understand.

What does “doesn’t work” do exactly? e.g. any error in the console?

The modal doesn't show.
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleConfirmCreateDestinationOrOriginModal is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (def.aspx:5489:68)

...which lead to me ask the same question with more specificity: what about the method name toggle* makes the onclick method undefined?

What debugging have you tried? e,g, replacing that function name with something simple like myFn but being careful not to change anything else.

I haven't replaced the toggle* with something very simple like myFn because I've effectively done that already when using display*. I've copy and pasted the method names between the files, to ensure no typos or encoding issues. I've stepped through what I can in run time.

The point of my suggestion is to absolutely ensure there are e.g. no typos or extraneous control characters or indeed (as you have now found) caching issues. Up to you whether you wanted to try it or not of course.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After getting similar issue with similar code, I suspected it is something to do with the way the JavaScript is cached. I did an Empty Cache and Hard Refresh (in Edge). Seems to have fixed the issue.
